# Is there a way to insert additional keys in an Encodable Object in Swift 4?

Tags: swift4, codable

As the question states: I have a struct conforming to the new `Encodable` protocol and would like to insert keys and values that are not present as variables or constants in the struct itself. My current workaround is adding them to the struct as constants with the sole purpose of being added to the generated JSON output. Is there a way to accomplish this in `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { ... }`?

---

### Background Information

I have a rather big Swift 4 project that needs a JSON output to generate statistics and visualizations outside the project itself, so nearly all of my structs, classes and enums conform to the new `Encodable` protocol. The Output is already working, but the readability is bad at some points. Especially in one struct that describes a field in a rasterized factory layout:

The field has a position (with coordinates `x: Int` and `y: Int`) and content of a custom `enum FieldType` containing the following cases:

```swift
case wall
case entrance(robots: Set<Robot>)
case exit(robots: Set<Robot>)
case workstation(object: Workstation)
case robot(object: Robot)
case empty
```

`Position`, `FieldType`, `Robot`, `Workstation` and the `Field` itself already implement `Encodable`, but the problem is that my JSON output for the fields looks like this:

```swift
...
{
    "content" : "empty",
    "position" : {
        "x" : 9,
        "y" : 6
    }
},
{
    "content" : "empty",
    "position" : {
        "x" : 10,
        "y" : 6
    }
},
{
    "content" : {
        "id" : 3,
        "state" : "idle",
        "type" : "C",
        "position" : {
            "x" : 11,
            "y" : 6
        }
    },
    "position" : {
        "x" : 11,
        "y" : 6
    }
},
{
    "content" : "empty",
    "position" : {
        "x" : 12,
        "y" : 6
    }
},
...
```

As you can see there is something other than an empty field at position (11, 6), but without knowing that only workstations have an idle state in my simulation, there is no way of knowing what content that field holds. So I tried adding a key `"object"` with the value `"workstation"` to my workstation model (analogical `"robot"` in the robot model) by defining CodingKeys as an enum:

```swift
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case object
    case id
    case state
    case type
    case position
}
```

This results in my `struct Workstation` no longer conforming to `Encodable`. So the only solution I found was adding a constant `let object = "workstation"`, but this is a constant with the sole purpose of being added to the output and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how `entrance` and `exit` field types will be encoded. They both have `Set<Robot>` as an associated value

Comment: @CodeDifferent [This is the output](https://codedump.io/share/rlEBBimwVlSH/1/excerpt-from-json-output) of the entrance field with 4 robots and two surrounding wall fields for comparison. The exit looks exactly the same, so there is no way of knowing which is which without knowing that the entrance is always in the first line of walls and the exit is in the last line. This too would be solved by some way of adding a key-value-pair in the encoding process.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a custom encoder for `FieldType`:

```
enum FieldType: Encodable {
    case wall
    case entrance(robots: Set<Robot>)
    case exit(robots: Set<Robot>)
    case workstation(object: Workstation)
    case robot(object: Robot)
    case empty

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        switch self {
        case .wall:
            try container.encode("wall")
        case .entrance(let robotset):
            try container.encode(robotset)
        case .exit(let robotSet):
            try container.encode(robotSet)
        case .workstation(let workstation):
            try container.encode(workstation)
        case .robot(let robot):
            try container.encode(robot)
        case .empty:
            try container.encode("empty")
        }
    }
}
```

(This assumes that `Robot` and `Workstation` are already `Encodable`)

Comment: This is what I did already to get to the above JSON output. What I'm asking is, if there's a possibility to add the line `"object" : "workstation"` to the encoded workstation without adding a constant like `let object = "workstation"` to the code of the workstation. Or in general: Is it possible to encode more than the variables and constants of a Swift Class, Struct, Enum, …